# Indexing and range querying _timestamp data

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling to understand _timestamp and how to use it correctly. I'm storing log data so the timestamp is very important. I'd like to be able to store the timestamp and query it by range. Whenever I a field with the name _timestamp I can never seem to get any results when I query by it. This happens whether I store and query using ISO 8601 text format or with millis as longs. Does anybody have a complete example of this working?

Test code when using text format (FWIW, this is unit test code running as a local node).

```
client.admin().indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest(indexName).mapping("log",
            "{\"_timestamp\": {\"enabled\": true, \"store\": \"yes\"}}"));
client.prepareIndex(indexName, "log", auditEvent.getId().toString())
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject().
                field("eventType", auditEvent.getEventType().toString()).
                field("_timestamp", auditEvent.getEventTime().toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime())).
                field("userId", auditEvent.getUserId()).
                endObject())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexNames.toArray(new String[] {})).setTypes("log")
            .setQuery(
                    QueryBuilders.
                    boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("eventType", eventType))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("_timestamp")
                            .from(interval.getStart().toString())
                            .to(interval.getEnd().toString())
                            )
                    )
                    .addField("_timestamp")
                    .execute().actionGet();
```

When I do the same query with a match all I can see the timestamp fields.

```
"hits" : {
  "total" : 2,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "audit-events-2013-03-04",
    "_type" : "log", 
    "_id" : "3d584830-8506-11e2-8365-24be05270b5c",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "fields" : {
      "_timestamp" : "2013-03-04T20:01:02.003Z"
    }
  }, {
    "_index" : "audit-events-2013-03-04",
    "_type" : "log",
    "_id" : "e6e382e0-84f5-11e2-8365-24be05270b5c",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "fields" : {
      "_timestamp" : "2013-03-04T18:04:05.006Z"
    }
  } ]
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the timestamp needs to be explicitly set using the timestamp method of the IndexRequest. Merely setting it on a field called _timestamp does not work.

```
IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = client.prepareIndex(indexName, "type1", auditEvent.getId().toString())
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject().
                        field("eventType", auditEvent.getEventType().toString()).
                        auditEvent.getEventTime().toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime())).
                        field("userId", auditEvent.getUserId()).                          endObject()).setTimestamp(Long.toString(auditEvent.getEventTime().getMillis()));
indexRequestBuilder
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```